# Select only the first lines that contain a repeated string

Tags: command-line

I have a file that looks like that:

```
2_00003 R034671 31.25   96  55  2   100 195 77  161 7e-07   47.8
2_00003 R034668 31.25   96  55  2   100 195 77  161 7e-07   47.8
2_00003 R034667 31.25   96  55  2   100 195 77  161 7e-07   47.8
2_00003 R034665 31.25   96  55  2   100 195 77  161 7e-07   47.8
2_00003 R034656 34.88   86  45  2   100 185 77  151 9e-07   47.4
2_00003 R034662 34.88   86  45  2   100 185 77  151 9e-07   47.4
2_00003 R034659 34.88   86  45  2   100 185 77  151 9e-07   47.4
2_00004 R014991 31.90   232 141 5   2   232 4   219 5e-28    111
2_00004 R009910 31.90   232 141 5   2   232 4   219 5e-28    111
```

I want to select just the first lines of the groups that start with the same string in the first column. So for the above file I want to select:

```
2_00003 R034671 31.25   96  55  2   100 195 77  161 7e-07   47.8
2_00004 R014991 31.90   232 141 5   2   232 4   219 5e-28    111
```

I thought to use simply

```
uniq -w 7 <file name>
```

But I have two problems:

1. I am not sure if `uniq` reports always the first occurrence (in my case in the first line)
2. sometimes in my file the string in the first column has a number of characters higher than 7, so my idea will not work

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using `sort -u` as  an alternative to `uniq`, specifying the first whitespace-separated field as key:

```
$ sort -uk1,1 file
2_00003 R034671 31.25   96  55  2   100 195 77  161 7e-07   47.8
2_00004 R014991 31.90   232 141 5   2   232 4   219 5e-28    111
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this in `awk`:

```
awk '$1!=last {last=$1; print}' file
```

which tests the first field of each line (`$1`) against its `last` value, and prints the line whenever `$1` changes, updating the `last` value as it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much!Sorry for the newby question, but using sort can I be sure that it will always take the first line of the input file? Is there a chance that it reorder the first line and it can give me for example the 2 or 3 line of the input file?

Comment: I did not quite get the `awk` comand, could you shortly explain it?

Comment: I *think* that `sort` should leave the order unchanged if the first fields are identical however the `awk` version is probably safer (and also probably more efficient, since it just makes a single pass - no sorting required).

Answer (score 1):

Another python approach:

- read the file
- list unique occurrences of the first column
- list the first occurrence in the list

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]

with open(file) as src:
    lines = src.readlines()
for l in [[l for l in lines if l.startswith(f)][0] for f in set([l.split()[0] for l in lines])]:
    print(l, end = "")
```

Run it with the textfile as argument:

```
python3 <script> <text_file>
```

#### Note

Although the option above turns out to be a fast one (tested on a file > 1000000 lines), it can be drastically faster (appr. 15% in the tests I ran) if we may assume the string in the first column does not occur on other positions in the records (probably a safe assumption). In that case we can skip the `startswith()` function:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]

with open(file) as src:
    lines = src.readlines()
for l in [[l for l in lines if f in l][0] for f in set([l.split()[0] for l in lines])]:
    print(l, end = "")
```

Comment: Your approach is better that my one. +1.

Comment: i think you don't need to use sorted function. Op just wants the first line.

Comment: @heemayl It is always the challenge here to make it short :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj absolutely true, removed it. It might be neat to present the *first lines* sorted though. the uniques were sorted, not the total list of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a script like this:

first_occurence.sh (set it to be executable)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Set bash to separate words by newlines only, not spaces
IFS=$'\n'
# read input
input=("$(cat)")

# get a list of unique keys - split input by space with awk for any length
unique_values=($(printf "%s\n" "${input[*]}" | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }' | uniq))

cur=0

# check each line of input for the key
for line in ${input[@]};
do  
    # wildcard matching
    if [[ "$line" == "${unique_values[$cur]}"* ]]
    then
        # print line if match, and move on to checking the next key
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
        cur=$((cur + 1))
    fi  
    # break the loop if we have used up all of our unique keys (only duplicates remain)
    if [ $cur -ge ${#unique_values[@]} ]
    then
        break
    fi  

done
```

Run by piping the file in:

```
./first_occurence.sh < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I think steeldriver's solution using `sort` is the best, although if you want to try something else check the following Python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python2
import re
def checking():
        if not check_list:
            result.append(list_of_lines[index - 1])
with open('/path/to/the/file') as f:
    list_of_lines = f.readlines()
    result = []
    for index in range(1, len(list_of_lines)):
        regex_current = re.search('^[0-9]_[0-9]+', list_of_lines[index])
        regex_previous = re.search('^[0-9]_[0-9]+', list_of_lines[index - 1])
        check_list = [x for x in result if x.split()[0] == regex_previous.group()]
        if regex_current == regex_previous:
            checking()
        else:
            checking()
print ''.join(result)
```